# The hierarchy of the type Class HijackBeforeMethod is inconsistent

Tags: spring

I am trying to implement AOP but when I implement `org.springframework.aop.MethodBeforeAdvice` interface then `HijackBeforeMethod` class gives inconsistent error in Eclipse ID.

```
package aop;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class HijackBeforeMethod implements org.springframework.aop.MethodBeforeAdvice{

    @Override
    public void before(Method arg0, Object[] arg1, Object arg2)
        throws Throwable {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: This compile error comes when a required library refered by the class is missing in the classpath

Answer (score 3):

aopalliance.jar has to be in the classpath.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem.

Solution:-First I was using spring-3.0 jars then I had added spring2.5 jars also.My class path contains 3.0 as well as 2.5 jars.Now it is working .But I am not sure about which particular jar it was showing problem.